# REACT and axios, how to protect?

Tags: reactjs, axios

My react app is now using axios to send and receive data from a set of php api.
Even if I obfuscate react code, in network panel of my chrome dev tools, I'm still able to see requests, headers, payload, so I'm wondering:

1. if anyone could replicate my calls to my api enpoint to manipulate data
2. if there's a way to protect this

Thank you

Comment: I guess that's a backend issue. Your api must be secured server side

Comment: yes but react, is a client library. So how to protect axios calls to be completely in clear?

Comment: What do you mean by "in clear"? If you can inspect an api call in your browser it's because you could perform that call. In a secured scenario the backend would assure that you can call the api _only_ under the conditions that: (1) you're authenticated, (2) your authentication has not expired, (3) you're authorized to perform that specific operation on that specific resource. So why should the call request be obfuscated to you?

Comment: Obviously that assumes that both client and server do not send sensitive data in clear while communicating, that the api response only contains the data you're supposed to get, that backend implements protection against CSRF, enables CORS, does not expose sensitive data even in case of exceptions, enforces HTTPS etc. In _this_ scenario I don't think the fact that you can inspect the api calls you're allowed to perform represents a huge vulnerability. Unless you let someone else access your browser while you're still authenticated (but in that case obfuscation wouldn't help...)